# MySQL ignore database case

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to ignore database (not table or column) name case in mysql? I have database `FOO` but I'd like to refer to it as `foo.some_table` or `FOO.some_table`. Setting `lower_case_table_names` doesn't seem to work. I've even migrated to a new database and recreated the database with name `foo` but now `FOO.some_table` doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to your question here: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). It's article in MySQL documentary about identifier case sensitivity.